# Pytorch - Optimizer is not updating its specified parameter

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, generative-adversarial-network

I'm trying to implement CLIP-based style transfer. The full code is [here](https://gist.github.com/ifilipis/6f2551274a4f8aefc20e76b2af0b1a48)

For some unknown reason optimizer doesn't change the weights of the latent tensor. I can confirm that the values are equal before and after the iteration steps. I've also made sure that `requires_grad` is True and tried various loss functions and optimizers.

Any idea why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

I see some problems with your code.

The optimizer takes in parameters. Parameters are supposed to be leaf nodes in your computation graph. In your case, you tell the optimizer to use latent as the parameter, but it must have complained as latent is the result of some computations.

So you detached latent, now latent becomes a leaf node. But when you detach the latent, the computation graph is no longer there, creating a new latent variable.

Also, to optimize a parameter, the loss should be a function of that parameter. I am not able to see if you are using latent in your loss function computation. So that can be another issue.

Comment: Right. So I detach latent even before anything happens and I don't touch it afterwards. I also tried random noise instead of the latent, same result. 


Then I use it to compute CLIP embeddings using ruclip_processor and ruclip. The first one uses torchvision to transform the image (made sure it stays as a tensor), could this be a problem? And then I compute loss between the style image CLIP and the one computed from latent. Is there a way to check where the graph breaks?

Comment: `I don't touch it afterwards`.. I can't figure out where you are using `latent` variable in your for loop (training loop). Since it is not part of the computation it won't be updated. 

`And then I compute loss between the style image CLIP and the one computed from latent` .. I don't see it in your training code (line 82-104). 

You create a new variable latent on line 71, where is it used?

Comment: I think I've found the issue. On line 86, where I compute one-hot vector from latent, in order to decode it and pass it to CLIP, the graph would break. ``vae_make_onehot`` returns a leaf tensor

Comment: Yup that is true. Sorry I missed that latent was being used there.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the issue. On line 86, where I compute one-hot vector from latent, in order to decode it and pass it to CLIP, the graph would break. vae_make_onehot returns a leaf tensor